# ERROR at line 1: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Tags: oracle, isql

I have this query and in order to query the manager department name always getting the error in title:

```
select e.employee_id e_id 
      , e.first_name || '  ' || e.last_name employee_name  
      , e.job_id 
      , e.department_id 
      , e.department_name 
      , e.salary || ' $ '
      , to_char(e.hire_date , ' day- dd - mon -yyyy' ) employee_hire_date
      , m.employee_id  m_id
      , m.first_name || '  ' || m.last_name manager_name  
      , m.job_id 
      , m.department_id  
      , m.department_name 
      , m.salary 
FROM employees e 
JOIN employees m 
  on m.employee_id = e.manager_id 
JOIN departments d
  on d.department_id = e.department_id 
JOIN departments d
  on d.department_id = m.department_id
```

Comment: You have departments joined twice with the same alias.. you would need to alias them differently... DE, (DepartmentEmployee) (DM) Department Manager perhaps. also update the select to use correct alias for department_name

Comment: Copy/Paste error?  You're joining the departments table twice (and with the same alias no less :-)).

Comment: But then D isn't being used anywhere either... so why have a join  my guess is the department_Name and perhaps ID's should be coming from the dual joins (which then need different aliases)

Answer (score 1):

The problem lays here:

```
JOIN departments d
  on d.department_id = e.department_id 
JOIN departments d
  on d.department_id = m.department_id
```

Either delete one both of them, since you are not selecting anything from those table, everything exists on `employee` table , or alias them differently.

```
JOIN departments d
  on d.department_id = e.department_id 
JOIN departments dd
  on dd.department_id = m.department_id
```

When you are trying to use two different columns with the same name/alias - this error will occur. Every column must have its own unique name/alias.

Answer (score 0):

You used the same alias twice. Try the following:

```
select e.employee_id e_id 
      , e.first_name || '  ' || e.last_name employee_name  
      , e.job_id 
      , e.department_id 
      , e.department_name 
      , e.salary || ' $ '
      , to_char(e.hire_date , ' day- dd - mon -yyyy' ) employee_hire_date
      , m.employee_id  m_id
      , m.first_name || '  ' || m.last_name manager_name  
      , m.job_id 
      , m.department_id  
      , m.department_name 
      , m.salary 
FROM employees e join employees m 
  on m.employee_id = e.manager_id 
JOIN departments d
  on d.department_id = e.department_id 
JOIN departments d2
  on d2.department_id = m.department_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Aliased the department names differently and corrected the select assuming department_Id and department name come from department.

```
select e.employee_id e_id 
      , e.first_name || '  ' || e.last_name employee_name  
      , e.job_id 
      , de.department_id            --***This line Updated alias
      , de.department_name          --***this line  Updated alias
      , e.salary || ' $ '
      , to_char(e.hire_date , ' day- dd - mon -yyyy' ) employee_hire_date
      , m.employee_id  m_id
      , m.first_name || '  ' || m.last_name manager_name  
      , m.job_id 
      , dm.department_id            --***This line Updated alias
      , dm.department_name          --***This line Updated alias
      , m.salary 
FROM employees e 
JOIN employees m 
  on m.employee_id = e.manager_id 
JOIN departments de                      --***this line Updated alias
  on de.department_id = e.department_id  --***this line Updated alias
JOIN departments dm                      --***this line Updated alias
  on dM.department_id = m.department_id  --***this line Updated alias
```